# How to display data from JSON source stored in React state - TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

I want to get a price of Bitcoin from this JSON array.
I tried several approaches with map() function, although without success. Why does the error say it's TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined? I saw a similar question but the answers there do not work for me.

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import React from 'react'
import './App.css';
import BoxComponent from './BoxComponent.js';
import Footer from './Footer.js'
import Header from './Header.js'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      data: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({loading: true})
    fetch("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.setState({
            data:  data,
            loading: false
          })
        })
  }

  

  render(){

    const price = this.state.loading ? "Loading.. :)" : this.data.map(price => <div>{price.bpi.gbp}</div>)
  
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        {price}
        <Footer />
      </div>
      
    );

  }

}

export default App;
```

This is a JSON file:

```
{"time":{"updated":"Feb 4, 2021 20:38:00 UTC","updatedISO":"2021-02-04T20:38:00+00:00","updateduk":"Feb 4, 2021 at 20:38 GMT"},"disclaimer":"This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org","chartName":"Bitcoin","bpi":{"USD":{"code":"USD","symbol":"&#36;","rate":"37,498.3099","description":"United States Dollar","rate_float":37498.3099},"GBP":{"code":"GBP","symbol":"&pound;","rate":"27,422.0266","description":"British Pound Sterling","rate_float":27422.0266},"EUR":{"code":"EUR","symbol":"&euro;","rate":"31,337.0376","description":"Euro","rate_float":31337.0376}}}
```

Comment: Well, what if `this.state.loading` is true? Then `price` is `"Loading.. :)"` and strings do not have a `map` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're applying `.map` on something that's not an array. I would recommend reading a bit more on what `map` is for. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a good starting point.

The first problem is that on the first render, `loading` will be false and your data will be undefined, so it will fail to display it. You could do this instead in your constructor:

```
this.state = {
  loading: true,
  data: undefined
}
```

Your render function has several issues:

First, to access state you should use `this.state.data` instead of `this.data`.

Then looking at the JSON file you've linked, the structure of your data looks like this:

```
{
  bpi: {USD: {…}, GBP: {…}, EUR: {…}},
  chartName: "Bitcoin",
  disclaimer: "This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org",
  time: {updated: "Feb 4, 2021 21:17:00 UTC", updatedISO: "2021-02-04T21:17:00+00:00", updateduk: "Feb 4, 2021 at 21:17 GMT"}
}
```

The path you're using for accessing the data doesn't match with this structure. I'll assume that you're looking for `bpi.GBP.rate` (but it could also be `bpi.GBP.rate_float`), in which case your `render` function should be:

```
 render(){
    const price = this.state.loading ? "Loading.. :)" : (<div>{this.state.data.bpi.GBP.rate_float}</div>)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        {price}
        <Footer />
      </div>  
    );
  }
```

Also, I wouldn't keep a string for "Loading" in the `price` variable, but that's a different topic.

Here you have a working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-breeze-qwvbb (I have omitted Header and Footer for obvious reasons).